# How to Change Firebase realtime database location?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently building react application with firebase, i don't recall which location i setup for firestore but according to latest docs of firebase you could change location of firebase realtime database which i am unable to change from their website. Console log:-
`@firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: Database lives in a different region. Please change your database URL to https://xxxxx-xxxx-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app (https://xxxxx-xxxx-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/)`

So, whenever i change url on the site and click go nothing works.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change a location of a existing database. You would need to migrate it manually to a new one that you setup to the location you want. The migration is very easy. Just export the old database into a json file and import it to the new one. You can read more about it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/locations?authuser=0#rtdb-locations).

Comment: changing project is not right solution. because i am using other functionality like FirebaseAuth and FirebaseDatabase

Comment: Sometime this is not a solution because if we try to manual migration there will be a downtime and database url will be changed and if you use this with your app, there will be another release needed.

Answer (score 27):

Try to set `databaseUrl` when you initialize the app.

```js
firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: 'key',
  authDomain: 'domain',
  projectId: 'id',
  storageBucket: 'storage',
  messagingSenderId: 'id',
  appId: 'id',
  databaseURL: 'paste-here-needed-database-url'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is **no option** to change the location of the firebase real-time database.

But there is a way to migrate,

You could create a new instance for the same project. Then you have to select the location that you need when creating the real-time database. After that, you have to export the old database and import it to the new one.

Comment: can you tell me how to do this with no downtime?